# "Network error 1:Connection refused" in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, kubuntu, kde, customization, plasma

I just installed Kubuntu 20.04, and when I go to System Settings --> Global Theme and click on "Get New Global Themes", I get an error message saying, "Network error 1:Connection refused". I get the same error whenever I try to get new themes, cursors, wallpapers, etc. via System Settings. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this problem? Thank you!

Comment: The Get New stuff was and is buggy: see https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/hr2nnp/why_is_the_get_new_stuff_system_is_so_unreliable/.